# VueJS 3 Composition API and TypeScript type issue when passing props into setup: Property 'user' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

I am struggling to work out what I am doing wrong to get TypeScript to understand that `props.user` is of type `UserInterface`, any advice or pointers would be amazing

vue@3.1.1, typescript@4.2.2, quasar@2.0.0-rc.3. This feels more like a native VueJS or TypeScript issue, rather than anything to do with Quasar

UserInterface for reference:

```
export default interface UserInterface {
  id: number,
  email: string,
  name: string,
  agent_id: string
}
```

Component:

```
<template>
  <q-avatar :color="color" :text-color="textColor" :size="size" :title="user.name" style="outline: 2px solid #ffffff">
    {{ initials(user.name) }}
  </q-avatar>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import UserInterface from 'logic/interfaces/UserInterface'
import {computed, defineComponent, PropType} from 'vue'

const colors: Record<string, string> = {
  A: 'blue',
  K: 'black',
  R: 'purple',
  S: 'primary'
}

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'UserIcon',
  props: {
    user: {
      type: Object as PropType<UserInterface>,
      required: true
    },
    size: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'lg',
      validator: function (value: string) {
        return ['xs', 'sm', 'md', 'lg', 'xl'].indexOf(value) !== -1
      }
    },
    textColor: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'white'
    }
  },
  setup (props) {
    const initial = props.user.agent_id.charAt(0)
    const color = computed(() => {
      return colors[initial] || 'green'
    })

    return {
      color,
      initials (name: string) {
        const names = name.split(' ')
        let initials = names[0].charAt(0)
        if (names.length > 1) {
          initials += names[names.length - 1].charAt(0)
        }

        return initials
      }
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

VueJS 3 documentation https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#using-with-composition-api states:

> On setup() function, you don't need to pass a typing to props parameter as it will infer types from props component option.

However, i keep getting a complication error, and i am not sure what i am missing

Result:

```
Failed to compile.

TS2339: Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{ [x: number]: string; } & { length?: number | undefined; toString?: string | undefined; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; concat?: string[] | undefined; join?: string | undefined; ... 15 more ...; includes?: ((searchElement: string, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean) | un...'.
    38 |   },
    39 |   setup (props) {
  > 40 |     const initial = props.user.agent_id.charAt(0)
       |                           ^^^^
    41 |     const color = computed(() => {
    42 |       return colors[initial] || 'green'
    43 |     })
```

Notes:
adding a `@ts-ignore` above the line in question does remove the error, but that's not solving the issue.

I've tried deleting node_modules and restarting everything to ensure its not a glitch

its running in a docker image

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For `validator` and `default` in the `prop` declarations, the [Vue docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props) prescribe either (1) using an arrow function, or (2) provide an explicit `this` parameter:

> #### WARNING
>
> Because of a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38845) in TypeScript when it comes to type inference of function expressions, you have to be careful with `validator` and `default` values for objects and arrays:
>
> ```js
> import { defineComponent, PropType } from 'vue'
>
> interface Book {
>   title: string
>   year?: number
> }
>
> const Component = defineComponent({
>   props: {
>     bookA: {
>       type: Object as PropType<Book>,
>       // Make sure to use arrow functions
>       default: () => ({
>         title: 'Arrow Function Expression'
>       }),
>       validator: (book: Book) => !!book.title
>     },
>     bookB: {
>       type: Object as PropType<Book>,
>       // Or provide an explicit this parameter
>       default(this: void) {
>         return {
>           title: 'Function Expression'
>         }
>       },
>       validator(this: void, book: Book) {
>         return !!book.title
>       }
>     }
>   }
> })
> ```

Anders Hejlsberg, lead architect of TypeScript, explains the issue in a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38845#issuecomment-651455328):

> This is a design limitation. Similar to [#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872). A[n] arrow function with no parameters is not context sensitive, but a function expression with no parameters is context sensitive because of the implicit `this` parameter. Anything that is context sensitive is excluded from the first phase of type inference, which is the phase that determines the types we'll use for contextually typed parameters. So, in the original example, when the value for the `a` property is an arrow function, we succeed in making an inference for `A` before we assign a contextual type to the a parameter of `b`. But when the value is a function expression, we make no inferences and the `a` parameter is given type `unknown`.

---

*Original answer:*

One of your props doesn't match the expected signature of `PropOptions`, which apparently breaks the type inference for the `props` argument in `setup()`. Specifically, TypeScript doesn't see that the signature of **`size.validator`** matches up with the type of [`PropOptions.validator`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/51d2be2/packages/runtime-core/src/componentProps.ts#L58) for some reason.

Interestingly, if you change `validator` to an arrow function, the type inference for `props` succeeds:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    size: {
      type: String,
      required: false,
      default: 'lg',
      //validator: function (value: string) { /*...*/ },
      validator: (value: string) => { /*...*/ },
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

## With `withDefaults` Syntax

The arrow function (as @tony19 mentioned) is also working for me with the `withDefaults` syntax.

See the [Vue Docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#default-props-values-when-using-type-declaration) for more information.

```
<script setup lang="ts">

interface Option {
    name: string;
    value: string;
}

interface Props {
    label?: string;
    options: Option[];
}
    
const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
    options: () => [
        { name: "Option 1", value: "1" },
        { name: "Option 2", value: "2" },
        { name: "Option 3", value: "3" },
    ],
});
```