# How to correctly extend props?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I am building a simple Vue3 app (using Typescript) and one of the components receives its data via `props`. With the basic version everything works fine:

```
   props: {
     when: String,
     data: Object
   },
```

I then wanted to extend `props` to add default values, validators, etc.

```
  props: {
    when: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
      validator(value: string) {
        return ['today', 'tomorrow', 'later'].includes(value)
      },
      required: true
    },
    data: {
      type: Object,
      default() {
        return {}
      },
      required: true
    },
  },
```

And then TS started to raise issues that I do not understand (all in `setup()`):

---

```
TS2345: Argument of type '"data"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string & ((number | unique symbol | "length" | "toString" | "toLocaleString" | "concat" | "join" | "slice" | "indexOf" | "lastIndexOf" | "every" | "some" | "forEach" | "map" | ... 29 more ... | ((searchElement: never, fromIndex?: number | undefined) => boolean)) & string)'.
```

for the line

```
let allEvents = toRef(props, 'data')
```

---

```
TS2339: Property 'when' does not exist on type 'Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<readonly unknown[] & { [x: number]: string; } & { [iterator]?: IterableIterator<string> | undefined; length?: number | undefined; toString?: string | undefined; toLocaleString?: string | undefined; ... 17 more ...; includes?: ((searchElement: string, fromIndex?: number | undefined) =>...'.
```

for the line

```
  if (props.when === 'today') {
    // ...
  }
```

---

There are a few more but I believe that I will fix them once I understand where the core of the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68074312/vuejs-3-composition-api-and-typescript-type-issue-when-passing-props-into-setup), where only the `validator` property was a regular function. In your case, both `validator` and `default` are regular functions (albeit in different props), which inexplicably breaks the type inference for the `props` argument in `setup()`. *I'm  seeking the root problem in an open [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68149092/why-does-regular-function-break-type-inference).*

Interestingly, your code creates this type for the `props` argument in `setup()`, which seems to be an intersection type of keys of `string`:

```js
(parameter) props: Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<readonly unknown[] & {
    [x: number]: string;
} & {
    [Symbol.iterator]?: IterableIterator<string> | undefined;
    length?: number | undefined;
    toString?: string | undefined;
    toLocaleString?: string | undefined;
    ... 19 more ...;
    flat?: unknown[] | undefined;
}> | Readonly<...>>>
```

#### Workaround

Instead of regular functions, use arrow functions (when functions are needed) in all `props` declarations:

```js
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    when: {
      type: String,
      default: '',

      //validator(value: string) {
      //  return ['today', 'tomorrow', 'later'].includes(value)
      //},
      validator: (value: string) => ['today', 'tomorrow', 'later'].includes(value), // ✅

      required: true
    },
    data: {
      type: Object,

      //default() {
      //  return {}
      //},
      default: () => ({}), // ✅

      required: true
    },
  },
})
```

...which creates this type for the `props` argument:

```js
(parameter) props: Readonly<LooseRequired<Readonly<{
    msg?: unknown;
    when?: unknown;
    data?: unknown;
} & {
    when: string;
    data: Record<string, any>;
} & {
    msg?: string | undefined;
}>>>
```

[GitHub demo](https://github.com/tony19-contrib/vue-props-arg-type)

Answer (score 1):

The validator should be an arrow function :

```
when: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  validator:(value:string)=>(['today', 'tomorrow', 'later'].includes(value)),
  required:true
 },
```

Comment: Are you sure? https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-props.html#prop-validation shows the version I used. The arrow version works as well, but this does not fix the issues in the question.